# Дискорд бот и ООП

Tags: python, ооп, discord.py

Уже какое-то время пишу ботов для дискорда, используя класс `discord.ext.commands.Bot`. Все боты написаны в процедурном стиле, но недавно на https://pypi.org/project/discord.py/ увидел, что, реализуя бота на `discord.Client`, можно свернуть его в отдельный дочерний класс.
Однако, попробовав свернуть своего бота на `discord.ext.commands.Bot` в класс, я столкнулся с некоторыми проблемами. Что здесь не так и как это исправить?

---

Рабочий бот, взятый с PyPI:

```py
import discord
from discord.ext import commands

bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix='>')

@bot.command()
async def ping(ctx):
    await ctx.send('pong')

bot.run('token')
```

Моя попытка свернуть его в класс:

```
import discord
from discord.ext import commands

class PingBot(commands.Bot):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.bot = super(*args, **kwargs)

    @bot.command()
    async def ping(ctx):
        await ctx.send('pong')

bot = PingBot(command_prefix='>')
bot.run('token')
```

Получаемое исключение:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "E:\Python\Example.py", line 4, in <module>
    class PingBot(commands.Bot):
  File "E:\Python\Example.py", line 8, in PingBot
    @bot.command()
NameError: name 'bot' is not defined
[Finished in 1.2s]
```

Comment: ну если в первом примере понятно, откуда берется декоратор `@bot`, то во втором ему откуда браться? вы пытаетесь обернуть функцию декоратором, которого нет в памяти

Comment: @finally это то понятно. Непонятно, что в данной ситуации можно предпринять

Comment: инициализировать бота в самом классе?